# Want pursue phd in Machine Learning but having a networking background

Tags: phd, career-path, changing-fields

My situation is similar to but not same as -[UG different field than phd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/undergraduate-research-field-different-from-phd-field)
Please skip to **edit 2** below if you want to know the problem in short.
**Details**
Talking of my career so far,

- I completed undergraduate in CS(computer-science) with WSN (wireless-sensor-networks) as thesis topic (Networks)
- Joined an MNC(multi-national-company) in Android GPS team and stayed for a year (More Networks! )
- Completed masters in CS with Social Network Analysis as main thesis. At this point I got interested in ML (machine-learning), NLP(natural-language-processing) and during my entire program I took related courses.
- Joined another MNC 11 months back, in their router OS QOS (quality-of-service) team (Networks again! )

I now want to apply for a PhD in ML / NLP from colleges like Carnegie Melon or N NUS, Singapore. But I find I don't have enough recommendation/ work experience in the same field.
What should I do - *Personal projects in these areas? Personal publication? Working with a startup in these fields ?*
Kindof desparate now to prepare and apply for some program within the next year.

I know its difficult to suggest something that will definitely work in my case but still wanted some advice from the community.

**Edit:-** Expanding on the acronyms as suggested in comments. Sorry for the long background but I wanted others to understand my situation by stating "some" of my backgound.

**Edit 2 : -**
Editing this again to highlight my problem in short. I want to pursue phd in fields(ML, NLP) in which I have somewhat less experience. My GPA is not extraordinary for an international student and have only single recommendation in the same. I do have a publication but not related to these areas. Any suggestions for getting my CV to be accepted by any faculty in ivory colleges?

Comment: (1) I don't see the difference between the linked question and yours. (2) We do not need to read your CV here. Please just ask your question. (3) You use too many acronyms, such as MNC, WSN, QOS, ... Please spell out them if you believe you need to provide those info.

Comment: @scaahu - 
(1) - the difference is that the person thereby just changing different fields altogether (physics -> maths) unlike me.
(2) thank you for reminding me, i know that but wanted to make sure that my exact background is known somewhat
(3)  edited the post!

Comment: I would expect no university to care about your undergrad except that it was in CS. And the "ivory tower" is infamous about ignoring non-academic work in general so your job is not likely to count for much the other. Your masters with courses in ML will be relevant, and Social Network Analysis as your thesis is plenty close enough to be a point in your favor. It seems to me you are a fairly ideal candidate already. Already working directly in the sub-field you want to pursue studies in is I would suggest uncommon. What particular problems are you facing -- have you had rejections based on...?

Comment: ML is still considered a relatively new field. I think your situation is not that different than the linked question. You'll need quite bit CS when you study ML just like Math students will need Math knowledge acquired from studying physics. Again, we don't need to read the detailed background of yours. Whether you gained experience from MNC or a small local company really does not matter. All you need to say is that you have network experience. Work experience will help the admission a little. The real question you need to concern are your GPA, recommendation letters and research potential.

Comment: @scaahu ,- Apologies for the mundane details, I am new to this niche of stackexchange. Updated the post again.